# Range of real values of $k$ in functional equation.

Tags: calculus

> If function $f(x)$ satisfy $f(3x) = kf(x)\;\forall x>0$ and $f(x) = 1-|x-2|\; \forall \; x \in \left[1,3\right]$
>
> If the area bounded by $y=f(x)\;,x-\bf{axis}$ in $1\leq x<\infty$ converge to a finite quantity.
>
> Then Range of values of $k$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $f(3x) = kf(x)\;,$ Then Replace $\displaystyle x\rightarrow \frac{x}{3}\;,$ Then $\displaystyle f(x) = kf\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)$

So Using Reciversively, We get $\displaystyle f(x) = kf\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)=k^2 f\left(\frac{x}{3^2}\right)=k^2 f\left(\frac{x}{3^3}\right)=......k^n f\left(\frac{x}{3^n}\right)$

and Given $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx\rightarrow \bf{finite\; number}$

I did not understand how can i solve that question, Help required, Thanks

Comment: Do both the functions $f(3x) = kf(x) $ and $f(x) = 1-|x-2|\;$ hold together $\forall \; x \in \left[1,3\right]$ ? Or should it be something else?

Comment: You need some hypothesis about $k$. Do you have it? Or have you to find it?

Answer (score 2):

We have $$I=\int_{1}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{3^{m}}^{3^{m+1}}f\left(x\right)dx
 $$ $$\stackrel{x=3^{m}y}{=}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^{m}\int_{1}^{3}f\left(3^{m}y\right)dy=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^{m}k\int_{1}^{3}f\left(3^{m-1}y\right)dy
 $$ $$=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^{m}k^{2}\int_{3^{m}}^{3^{m+1}}f\left(3^{m-2}y\right)dy=\dots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^{m}k^{m}\int_{1}^{3}f\left(y\right)dy
 $$ and now since $\int_{1}^{3}f\left(y\right)dy=1
 $ we have $$I=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^{m}k^{m}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{1-3k}}
 $$ assuming $\left|k\right|<\frac{1}{3}
 $. If $\left|k\right|\geq\frac{1}{3}$ the integral diverges.

Comment: Thanks Marco cantari, would you like to explain me how can we get $$3\sum_{n\geq1}nk^{n}\int_{1}^{3}f\left(x\right)dx$$

Comment: @juantheron There is a mistake, now it works.